# Reflection and Socket

Tags: java, sockets, reflection

I'm working in a java project to do a server-client with sockets. We send and receive data using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream.

Now, our teacher explained a little about reflection and RMI. I understood that I can use or RMI or socket, but not both. About reflection, it's possible (or is indicated or contraindicated) use with socket? My client can access a Class that exists only in the server, to add a data in the database for example? Or it's necessary import the .class in my client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we your are using sockets the objects (class) are not shared between your client and server. you will need to share them or recreate them manually in your code.

Better practice is having a :
- beans.jar project.
- server.war that contains beans.jar
- client.war that coontains beans.jar

;)